# Rails 4 Adding Tags to a Micropost, having template missing issues; Railstutorial add ons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I am working on building an extension off of Hartl's Rails tutorial micropost app, and trying to add tagging with the Acts as Taggable on Gem.
Everything is working ok, but if I click on one of my tags in one of my microposts, I get this  template erorr:

Template is missing
Missing template microposts/tagged, application/tagged with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.

Here is my code, let me know if you see any reason why this is not working.

```
Gemfile:

    ...
    gem 'acts-as-taggable-on' , '~> 2.4.1'
    ...

Routes.rb
    ...
    match 'tagged',   to: 'microposts#tagged',    :as => 'tagged', via: 'get' 
    match 'tags/:tag', to: 'microposts#tagged', as: :tag, via: 'get'
    end

Microposts_helper.rb
    module MicropostsHelper
    include ActsAsTaggableOn::TagsHelper
    ...

_micropost.html.erb
    <li>
    ...
    <span class="tags">
        <%= micropost.tag_list %>
    ...
    </li>

micropost.rb
    class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :user
      acts_as_taggable #tags, this line and below
      acts_as_taggable_on :tags
      default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC')  
    ...

Microposts_controller.rb
    class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
      before_action :correct_user,   only: [:destroy]  

      # for tagging:
      def index
      if params[:tag]
          @microposts = Micropost.tagged_with(params[:tag])
        else
          @microposts = Micropost.all
        end
      end

      def create
        @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
        if @micropost.save
          flash[:success] = "Gif post created!"
          redirect_to root_url
        else
          @feed_items = []
          render 'static_pages/home'

        end
      end

    ...

      def tagged #more for tagging
        if params[:tag].present?
          @microposts = Micropost.tagged_with(params[:tag])
        else
         @microposts = Micropost.postall
        end
      end

_micropost_form.html.erb
    <%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class='field'>
        <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Post your message..." %>
        <%= f.label :tags, "Tags (separated by commas):" %>
        <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
    ....
 schema.rb
    create_table "taggings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "taggable_id"
    t.string   "taggable_type"
    t.integer  "tagger_id"
    t.string   "tagger_type"
    t.string   "context",       limit: 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tag_id"
  add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"

  create_table "tags", force: true do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end
     ....
_feed_item.html.erb
...
<span class="tags">
        Tags: <%= raw feed_item.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %>
    </span><br />
...
```

That's the long and short of it.  I've tried googling around to fix this problem with no luck.  I used some code from this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging

Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's expecting a file to render in app/views/microposts/tagged.html.erb where looking at your code quickly you should be putting something to display the microposts

Comment: I tried creating this file, I copied the data from _micropost.html.erb, now am getting NameError in Microposts#tagged
Showing app/views/microposts/tagged.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined local variable or method `micropost'.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a lot of microposts _micropost.html.erb will render one.

Just put `<%= render @microposts %>` in tagged.html.erb nothing else and it should pass the collection onto the partial for each micropost

Comment: This worked great, thanks.  Only problem is, now I'm not sure how to proceed if I want my @microposts to render in a similar style of html format as seen in the _feed_item.html.erb file.  Tags aren't rendering as links on the tagged.html.erb page.